# Sitecore publishing and lag of upto 30 seconds

Tags: sitecore, publishing

We have noticed an interesting issue in our Sitecore install. Any auto publish or scheduled publish jobs takes a long time when compared to our other environments. Between each individual job there seems to be a lag of anywhere from 5 to 30 seconds. In our other environments we do not see any lags as difference between 2 publishing jobs in those environments is less than a second.

We have tried the following up until now -

- We have already checked for differences between the problematic and
  other environments and do not see any differences in configuration or
  code.

  - The caches are pretty similar in all environments.
  - We tried enabling parallel publishing but that did not make much difference.
  - Indexing is also very quick in the problematic environment and finishes within one second for each job.

At this point, we are not sure what is causing this issue. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Can yo check the size of(row numbers) the Event/Publish Queue Tables in the Master and Core Databases? It is the usual problem when the environments feel laggy and publishes are slow. It is recommended by Sitecore to have a maximum of 1000 rows in each table.

Comment: I'll check and get back to you.

Comment: Here is what i found
Core Database
Event Queue - 81663
PublishQueue - 0
History - 0

Master Database
Event Queue - 216
PublishQueue - 236
History - 171

Web Database
Event Queue - 23242
PublishQueue - 0
History - 20444

Comment: And these numbers are after we truncated this data yesterday. After truncation as well, the publishing wasn't that fast. Makes me think that Sitecore is trying to do something with this. This seems a very large number for a few publishes, specially core event queue.

Comment: Are you on 7.2 ? There is a problem with Publish Related items sometimes that causes such problems.

Answer (score 0):

As Sitecore [would allow maximum one publish to be executed **at once** to avoid data corruption](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/How-does-publishing-work#how-does-publishing-work), I would assume you might add publish jobs faster than they are processed => queueing.

In order to make accurate conclusions, the publish operation needs to be profiled - that will give an answer on wallclock time spend (like ~80% on network + database operations, only 20% in Sitecore code).

You'll need [to collect a few 20-second long profiles](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/How-to-investigate-slowness-with-PerfView) while observing publishing lag.
From there you'll see how the time is spent.

Please keep in mind that seeing obsolete content in the browser does not necessarily mean publishing is slow - there are [100500 caching layers in the middle that can influence](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/How-to-figure-out-why-new-content-is-not-showing-up).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have similar issue.

Do have multiple IaaS Sitecore installations. 2 environments (hosted on onr VM) have much better performance (package installation, publish etc).

Also have 2 more Sitecore installations on other VM, and publish and package installation there is 4-5 times slower, than on first VM.
I've used the same Sitecore installation configuration, but with different prefix.

In my case i was migrating from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.2. Used Unicorn to migrate data, and saw, that content publish (seems, writes to master) is slow right away.

So, on first 2 environments migration with unicorn, content publish and package installation was a way faster, but on 2 other this process is slower.